# Django template loop through dict and render it value below key

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views, django-templates

I'm using Django template to generate an HTML page in which I'm going through a dict, the key is an URL to a picture, the value is the caption to that image, what I'd like to render is in each row, the caption being right below the image, and render all entries (always four) in a dict in the same row, here's my code so far:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 p-2">
{% for one_metric in url_list %}
<ul>
    <tr>
    {% for url, caption in one_metric.items %}
        <td><img width="350" height="300" src="{{ url }}"></td>
        <td>{{ caption }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

What ended up rendering is the caption listed on the ***right*** of the picture instead of being ***below*** it, I've searched through the Internet but didn't figure it out, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have wrapped both the comment and the image in separate `<td>` elements. This causes the caption to appear next to the image as its in another cell on a row. What you likely want to do is keep them in the same cell and wrap the caption in a `<div>` element to ensure it is it's own entity on the next line in that row. You also want to render all 4 entries left to right in a row so use element `<table>` not `<ul>` as `<tr>` isn't allowed in `<ul>` so they are forced vertical rather than horizontal.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 p-2">
{% for one_metric in url_list %}
<table>
    <tr>
    {% for url, caption in one_metric.items %}
        <td><img width="350" height="300" src="{{ url }}"><div>{{ caption }}</div></td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there's a few things going awry here:

1. You are using CSS classes to set up a grid, but you then use table rows and cells (TR and TD)
2. You have no TABLE tag, but an Unordered List UL tag instead.
3. TD Cells go left to right by default, but you want cells to be one on top of the other.

The simplest way forward here is to set up an actual table, and have the info you want in single cells.  This would look something like this:

```
 <table>
{% for one_metric in url_list %}
    <tr>
    {% for url, caption in one_metric.items %}
        <td>
            <img width="350" height="300" src="{{ url }}">
            <br>
            {{ caption }}
        </td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This will solve your immediate problems with a proper table, the elements in the same cell, and a line break to make the caption start on a new line.  If you want to use a bit more semantic HTML you can associate the caption and the image:

```
        <td>
            <figure>
                <img width="350" height="300" src="{{ url }}">
                <figcaption>{{ caption }}</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </td>
```

Fig captions are block elements so don't need the newline